# Flask/Python - handling dropdown to open different HTML pages

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm learning flask and Python along with HTML and CSS. I've got a Flask template to render a dropdown.

What I need to do is this: When you select a value from the dropdown it opens a new HTML page corresponding to the value chosen(different page for different options chosen).

I tried searching the web but couldn't get much resources. When I submit the dropdown option by submit button the page gives a error message saying:

**Method Not Allowed**

**The method is not allowed for the requested URL.**

Please guide me to the best possible solution.

Below is my code.

pro.html

```
    <form name="startpage" method="POST" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <select name = "method_cipher" id = "method_cipher"> 
                <option value="Encrypt">Encrypt</option>
                <option value="Decrypt">Decrypt</option>
            </select>
            <select name = "cipher_type" id = "cipher_type"> 
                <option value="Caesar">Caesar</option>
                <option value="Transposition">Transposition</option>
                <option value="Reverse">Reverse</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="success" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

test.py

```
    import flask
    APP = flask.Flask(__name__)
    @APP.route('/')
    def index():
        return flask.render_template('pro.html')
    @APP.route("/test" , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def test():
        if flask.request.method == 'POST':
            select = flask.request.form.get('method_cipher')
            if(select == 'Encrypt'):
                return flask.render_template('lastpage.html')
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        APP.debug=True
        APP.run()
```

EDIT - I want to open different web pages(HTML page) for the different dropdown option as chosen by the user like when user chose "Encrypt" and submit I want to open "lastpage.html" if he chose "Decrypt" then any other page and so on for different options. But it is not happening so.

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: When I submit the dropdown option by submit button the page gives a error message saying:

Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Comment: See my answer. Next time please include the full traceback. That helps us a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form in `pro.html` sends the data to the url specified by the `action` attribute. If you leave that out or set it to an empty string like you did the requests goes to the same page which is `/`.

But you already set up the form handling in a different view function. You probably want to post to that one.

So change your form to post to the correct url

```
<form ... action="/test" ...>
```

That will work but it is not a good idea to hardcode the target url in the template. I assume you are using `jinja` so you can let it insert the url for you

```
<form ... action="{{ url_for("test") }}" ...>
```

Take a look at the [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#url-building) function if you haven't already.

Comment: On doing the above changes what i got is a blank page (test). But what i want is to open the page "lastpage.html" whenever the value of the first dropdown is chosen as "Encrypt".

Comment: @dexter the fact that you got a blank page and no error at all means that the view function rendered your template. If it didn't you would have gotten an error like "view function did not return a response". Can you update your question so i can see what you are doing now?

Comment: @dexter I think I don't understand your current problem. When I copy your code, apply my fix and start it I get the contents of `lastpage.html` when I choose `"Encrypt"` in the select box

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
<select onchange ="if (this.value)window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="/target1">test1<option>
    <option value="/target2">test2<option>
</select>
```